# Improving code for similar code found

Tags: python, optimization, code-climate

I passed codeclimate to my code, and I obtained the following:

> Similar code found in 1 other location

This is my code:

```
stradd = 'iterable_item_added'
if stradd in ddiff:
    added = ddiff[stradd]
    npos_added = parseRoots(added)
    dics_added = makeAddDicts(localTable, pk, npos_added)
else:
    dics_added = []
strchanged = 'values_changed'
if strchanged in ddiff:
    updated = ddiff[strchanged]
    npos_updated = parseRoots(updated)
    dics_updated = makeUpdatedDicts(localTable, pk, npos_updated)
else:
    dics_updated = []
```

Where `iterable_item_added` and `values_changed` are repeated. How to change it?

Comment: without seeing the rest of the `...` code, it's not possible to decide. Frankly, doing a procedure for this would be overkill. Is there a way to up the threshold of the copy/paste detection?

Comment: Use a variable? Also, why are you calling `keys()` instead of testing `… in ddiff`? Seems simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre check my update

Comment: @5gon12eder I updated as you suggest but it is not the issue per se. Thank you for your advice about `keys()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just abstract the parameters and create an helper method:

```
def testmethod(name,localTable,m,ddiff,pk):
    if name in ddiff:
        npos = parseRoots(ddiff[name])
        rval = m(localTable, pk, npos)
    else:
        rval = []

    return rval
```

the call it:

```
dics_added = testmethod('iterable_item_added',localTable,makeAddDicts,ddiff,pk)
dics_updated = testmethod('values_changed',localTable,makeUpdatedDicts,ddiff,pk)
```

note: be careful when factorizing code, you can introduce bugs (and make code better readable :)).

Also: that helper method forces to pass a lot of local variables. Maybe creating an object and member variables would simplify even more.

In that case, it appears to be a bit "overkill" to do that in order to make your review tool shut up.